# Recognizing function call pattern with Flex/Lex

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, yacc

I'm trying to write a Cminus (C-subset) compiler, but my professor demands that we are able to handle `input()` and `output()` functions as system calls (on the last semester we implemented a RISC CPU that can handle those instructions).

For the `input()` part, I managed to get it right on the first try (just do a pattern that matches `"input()"`), but the problem comes with `output()`. Since this function is supposed to take an array or a variable as an argument, I would assume that on the Lex patterns I need to have something like this (referencing what I read [here](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~pjj/cs212/ex2_str_comm.html)):

```
digito          [0-9]
numero          {digito}+
letra           [a-zA-Z]
identificador   {letra}+({letra}|{digito})*
input           "input()"
outputStart     "output("
outputSimple    {identificador}
outputComplex   {identificador}"["identificador"]"
outputEnd       ")"
output          {outputStart} ({outputSimple} | {outputComplex}){outputEnd}
```

But I have the following definition on my grammar:

```
type: INT | VOID;
fun_decl: type ID LPAREN params RPAREN comp_decl;
```

where ID is a token given from Lex to Bison when it matches a string to `identificador`

My problem is that only `fun_decl` is being matched, but I digress.

To summarize, how do I match `output(var)` or `output(array[i])` to a pattern? Is it even possible?

Edit1:
After reading the response from @rici I managed to come up with this code for the productions, moving everything away from Lex/Flex, dealing only with Bison-YACC (rest of the code ommited for clarity):

```
ativacao    : id LPAREN args RPAREN
                {   
                    if(strcmp($1->attr.name, "output") == 0)
                    {
                        /*code for output system call*/
                    }
                    else if(strcmp($1->attr.name, "input") == 0)
                    {
                        /*code for input system call*/
                    } else{
                        /*code for other function activations*/
                    }
                }
            ;
```

Comment: This is a job for a parser, not a lexical analyser. Too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you have a production to recognize function declarations:

```
fun_decl: type ID LPAREN params RPAREN comp_decl;
```

It seems reasonable that you would have a production to recognize function calls:

```
expr     : /* ... */
         | ID LPAREN arguments RPAREN

arguments: /* empty */
         | exprs
exprs    : expr
         | exprs COMMA expr
```

That covers the grammar part. Trying to do any of this in the lexer violates the clear distinction between lexical analysis and parsing, which you might want to review. (Also, it will turn out to be infeasible, as you have discovered.)

In your semantic actions, you'll need to check to see what the `ID` in the function call is, and insert appropriate code if it turns out to be a system call.

Comment: I do have a production for function calls, I just didn't think it would be useful here. But as you suggested it might be the only way.

Comment: I've added the code I came up with on my original post, if you want to look at it. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @pedro: that looks appropriate to me.

Answer (score -1):

What about `array[0]` or `array[1]`? Are they allowed? I don't see how fun_dec1 can match, because there's no return type specified here - I guess you have a function call definition in your grammar too, surely it would be matching that?

The one function call grammar definition should be sufficient, I'm not sure why you're trying to hardcode `input`/`output` functions into the grammar.